# @MappingTarget generate "Can't generate mapping method from iterable type to non-iterable type." error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a complex set of Data objects that are filled at different points in time during my process and then needs to be mapped to other objects. I was using mapstruct and the `@MappingTarget` annotation in order not to recreate a new instance of my object each time I needed to add or modify some properties but I'm now facing an issue.

I've got a code structure similar to that :

```java
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class A {
    
    String nameA;
    
    List<C> namesC;
}
```

```java
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class B {
    
    String nameB;
    
    List<D> namesD;
}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class C {
    
    String nameC;
}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class D {
    
    String nameD;
}
```

And then my mappers :

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface CDMapper {

    @Mapping(target="nameC", source="nameD")
    C DtoC(D d);
    
    List<C> DstoCs(List<D> ds);
}
```

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

@Mapper(uses = {CDMapper.class})
public interface ABMapper {

    @Mapping(target="nameA", source="nameB")
    A BtoA(B b);
    
    @Mapping(target="namesC", source="ds")
    void fillList(@MappingTarget A a, List<D> ds);
}
```

**I have an error on the line `void fillList(@MappingTarget A a, List<D> ds);` : "Can't generate mapping method from iterable type to non-iterable type.".**

If I remove the `@MappingTarget` annotation I don't have any issue anymore but I have to change the return type to A.

I don't understand why this error would appear when using the annotation. Does anybody know why and can explain it to me ? Is there a way to keep the annotation in order to not instantiate a new `A` object each time I call my mapper ?

UPDATE : I have created a [Github issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3093).

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

Mapstruct thinks that you want to map the `iterable` `List<D> ds` to the `non-iterable` `A a`.

This is not supported.

### Work-around

A work-around would be to introduce an unused variable.

As soon as there is more than 1 value mapstruct will assume that these are properties to be set inside the `@MappingTarget` instead of something to be mapped to it.

```java
    default void fillList(A a, List<D> ds) {
        fillList(a, ds, false);
    }

    @Mapping(target="namesC", source="ds")
    void fillList(@MappingTarget A a, List<D> ds, boolean unused);
```

### Improvement for mapstruct

An enhancement to mapstruct would be to support this situation by first checking if the field is directly assignable to a property with the same name or mapped through `@Mapping` before giving this error.

You can check if there is already an issue to get this supported at the [Mapstruct github issues](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues) page. If there is not one feel free to create it.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I will try asap, but it feels odd to me because, let's say instead of having two `List` in `A` and `B` you had only the objects `C` and `D`. Then doing `@Mapping(target="namesC", source="ds") void fillList(@MappingTarget A a, D d);` works perfectly fine, and there is only one property and both object are differents so what happens in this case ? I will definitly create a github issue tomorrow !

Comment: that might just work as you'd expect, because they're both objects and not an iterable vs an object. But any other fields that match would also be mapped.